# RelativeLayout margin not working inside listView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm wondering why what i'm trying to accomplish isn't working

Relative layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#649760" 
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How it looks on android studio preview:

[image: Android studio preview. notice the white after the green]

notice the white right to the green.

I've also added a list_view.xml in order to remove the divider and control the background color

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:background="#ffffff">
 </ListView>
```

but what i'm getting (screen capture from my mobile) is that the green captures all the remaining width.

btw i've solved it by giving a padding to list_view.xml but i cannot use such a solution because i have multiple views in the list and not all of them should get this kind of margin

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and will be rewarded with thumbs up (-:

[image: Screen capture, no white]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows of a ListView use `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, when you check out the doc :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.LayoutParams.html

you can notice that they aren't any margin available.

So the workaround is to add another `View` on top of your cells, this should work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#649760"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

An other workaround, add a View at the right of your "rootView" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#649760">

    <View
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know it's not the best for performance, but it's the only workaround I found.

Comment: yeah well, your solution works and i already implemented it like that (but instead LinearLyaout i've used Relative layout) but now i have 2 nested layout in a list layout and i guess it is an overkill. my question was more of why it's not working (-:

Comment: thanks again for your answer (-: i didn't give any margin/padding to the listView, only to the relativeLayout view. that is why i'm surprised it didn't work

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you, the rows of your ListView (so here your RelativeLayout) have for LayoutParams the type AbsListView.LayoutParams because they are the childs of a ListView. So the margins are ignored.

Comment: yeah well, i accepted your answer as the correct answer but i just wish that someone will show a more performance wise solution.